# F-theory questions on MSSM vs. SM compatibility and on de Sitter vacua

Tags: string-theory, standard-model, supersymmetry, de-sitter-spacetime, mssm

Having read https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.03947, https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00009 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00009, I noted the use of MSSM (Minimal Supersymmetric Standard Model) as if equivalent to SM, yet it is instead supersymmetric. They show derive some or a lot of MSSM models including in 4D. There are many more related papers.

**Question 1**: has any derivation from F-theory, led to SM (i.e. non supersymmetric)? I see mention of supersymmetry breaking but no mention that it would not still involve MSSM.

**Question 2**: There are many arguments to suspect that de Sitter Vacua are in the swampland (except for the de Sitter vacua construction schemes that define spacetime effective potentials that are positive and stable metastable or unstable). Is anything different for F-theory (especially when at 4D)? I haven't seen any result suggesting extracting a de Sitter vacuum from the derivation of 4D models from 12D F-theory. Is there any? I asked because of section 4.3 in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9602022 that relies on https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506101 with non supersymmetric strings in 4D to explain the small cosmological constant. Would the broken supersymmetry allow de Sitter vacua then and be in the string landscape.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.